# Can't revert winforms project to .net 3.5

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I have been unable to revert a winforms project from .net 4 back to .net 3.5 due to bugs in visual studio 2010. The program manager says in a forum it was not a design goal to permit round trip development to previous versions (!). The error is in the resx files:

error RG0000: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557469/visual-studio-2010-generates-invalid-assembly-in-some-cases

```
"This is the intended way in which the product was designed. And, we do not support round-tripping with previous versions of the product. As such, I am resolving the issue, "By Design"."
```

I tried manually editing a resx file back to 3.5 and couldn't do it. Any suggestions for this appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't got a previous version for what ever reason, the simplest solution would be to delete the .resx files and recreate them in the 3.5 version of the project. Take a copy of the project so you can open the offending .resx files and copy the resources to the clipboard. Pasting them back into the 3.5 version should just paste the content.

Answer (score 1):

Get the last working version just before you did the upgrade from source control. You do use source control right?

Comment: Problem is that there have been many UI changes since converting to .net 4. The last 3.5 version UI is out of date.